# Canon EOS utility doesn't work on a low-resolution netbook — any alternatives?

Tags: canon, software, canon-60d, eos-utility

I want my Canon 60D to display a live video feed in my netbook, so that I can use it as an external display to have a bigger video preview. Unfortunately, Canon EOS Utility doesn't want to install, saying I need a resolution 1024*768 or higher (my netbook has 1024*600). As google tells me, this is a common problem.

How can I go around this problem, or what alternative software can I use to have a live video feed in my netbook? I have Windows XP and Ubuntu 11.04 both installed on it. I can use either to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you have a VGA output? You could set a second display with a 1024*768 resolution and hopefully trick the EOS Utility installer.

Comment: @Andres: that sounds good, I don't know why I didn't think about that. I'm going to try that ..

Comment: If that does not work, a lot of notebooks have a virtual desktop option. Look for one in the Display configuration. It lets you configure a scrolling larger desktop, say 1280x1024. I'll guess you can probably get a third-party app to do that.

Comment: You could also try copying an already installed version (inside the Program Files folder).

Comment: @Andres: Your solution with the VGA output worked perfectly, so if you can answer it officially, I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Do you have a VGA output?**

You could set a second display with a 1024*768 resolution and hopefully trick the EOS Utility installer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Darktable

[Darktable](http://darktable.sourceforge.net/) is quite usable on netbook screen (1024×600), because it can go full screen and can hide all panels when you don't use them (and can also hide rarely used plugins too). It works well on Ubuntu, there are two PPAs (for release and unstable versions).

The problem is usually its memory consumption, so get ready that it may crash often if you have only 1GB of RAM (better with latest patches, with reduced mipmap cache and smaller thumbnail resolution, and all other apps closed). Another problem is that it is still not yet as stable and reliable as commercial apps, definitely not a tool to get things done without risks of some broken plugin or unexpected image artifacts (though I use git version, it bites).

But even with its small problems, I still *enjoy* processing photos in Darktable, because it allows me to achieve what I cannot do so easily in other (open source) RAW processors.

On my desktop its window can be downsized to 966×558 pixels:

[image: darktable screenshot 966x558 px]

Comment: Darktable can display a live video feed from the camera? Cuz thats what the question is asking.

Comment: @rfusca It supports [tethered shooting](http://darktable.sourceforge.net/features.shtml), I suppose this is what “bigger video preview” is about. Unfortunately, I cannot tell how it works, because my camera doesn't support tethering. Still I am sure it is about taking photos, not video; just with a bigger electronic viewfinder. This is how it looks: [http://flic.kr/p/8wWxuh](http://flic.kr/p/8wWxuh)

Comment: Looks like your screen shot is no longer available